# Gremlin Query Returns Different Structures Based on Page Size: Array vs Single Map

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlin-server

I'm working with Gremlin queries and encountering an unexpected behavior based on the page size specified. When I set the page size to more than one, the query returns an array of group maps under the groups key, as expected:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "groups": [
    {
      "admin_team_ids": ["xxx"],
      "created_at": "2024-02-28T23:19:01Z",
      ...
    },
    {
      "admin_team_ids": ["xxx"],
      "created_at": "2024-02-28T23:19:01Z",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I change the page size to 1, the structure changes, and the groups key is followed by a single map instead of an array:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "groups": {
    "admin_team_ids": ["xxx"],
    "created_at": "2024-02-28T23:16:37Z",
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm not sure which part of the Gremlin query is causing this behavior. Here's a snippet of the query(with pageSize=1; to change it to be more than 1, just update the "1" in the below snippet):

```
g.V('fcc6f904-d849-8293-f5c4-5c121e8e37df').
  outE('test-edge').inV().hasLabel('group').
  order().by('name', asc).
  valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens).
  fold().as('groups', 'count').select('groups', 'count').by(range(local, 0, 1)).by(count(local))
```

(I am trying to get the direct outgoing vertices of a particular vertex, with pagination)

Is this a known behavior with Gremlin queries, or could it be related to how the results are being processed? How can I ensure that the groups key always returns an array, regardless of the page size?

This is not blocking us technically because we can do some special conditional checking when the page size is 1, but just wanted to know the best way to handle this scenario. Thank you in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

Given that Gremlin will create a list result if there is more than one value, but return just the value if there is only one, probably the easiest way to handle this, and to get a consistent result format (assuming that is the goal), is to end the query with something like `unfold().fold()`. The `unfold` will do nothing if there is only one result but will remove the list if there is more than one result. The `fold` will then guarantee that all results come back in a list.

Here is a simple example of how this works

```
gremlin> g.V()
==>v[0]
==>v[1]

gremlin> g.V().fold().limit(local,1)
==>v[0]

gremlin> g.V().fold().limit(local,2)
==>[v[0],v[1]]

gremlin> g.V().fold().limit(local,1).unfold().fold()
==>[v[0]]

gremlin> g.V().fold().limit(local,2).unfold().fold()
==>[v[0],v[1]]
```

It's also fine to just special case the length of 1 case in the application logic instead.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, Kelvin! However, the unfold().fold() approach doesn't completely address our issue. Our situation is slightly more intricate because the query requires pagination, resulting in a structure like:
```
{
  "count": 2,
  "groups": [...]
}

```
as opposed to a straightforward array like:
```
[v[0],v[1]]

```

Comment: When I incorporate unfold().fold() to the end of my query:

The result I get is: 
```
[{
  "count": 2,
  "groups": [...]
}]
```
This still isn't the desired outcome. I've experimented with different placements for unfold().fold() but haven't found a solution that works.
For now, I'll handle this with application logic, but I'm open to any suggestions you might have on refining the query. Thanks again for taking a look at this!!

Comment: Did you put the `unfold().fold()` inside the `by` modulator containing the `range` step?

Comment: Ahh I see, if I put `unfold().fold()`  inside the `by` modulator containing the `range` step, it would produce the correct count number. I had previously appended it at the end of the query. Thanks a lot for the tip!